# error: annotation value not of an allowable type

Tags: java, android, butterknife

trying to build my project  but this error  shown up on this lines

```js
 @BindView({R.id.view_1, R.id.view_2, R.id.view_3, R.id.view_4, R.id.view_5})
    View[] views;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
```

App module dependencies

```js
dependencies {
   final SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION = '27.0.2'
    final COLOR_PICKER_VERSION = '1.5'
    final BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION = '8.4.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2"
    compile "com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5"
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'



    compile project(':library')
}
```

and Project Gradle

```js
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Apps\blabla\blabla\blabla\wallpaper\src\main\java\com\cleveroad\wallpaper\SettingsFragment.java

error: annotation value not of an allowable type

Comment: Have you tried `@BindViews` (plural) instead?

Comment: @pushasha more insight will really helpful

Comment: Not much insight to be offered, honestly. Your annotation is written as `@BindView`, but it should be `@BindViews` (with an 's' on the end). `@BindView` is for binding a single view, whereas `@BindViews` is for binding a collection of views. If that ends up being your issue, let me know, and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @pushasha i did what you told me changed BindView with a BindViews but "Cannot find symbole Class Bindviews show up T_T , should i upload a picture of the full  code if that doesn't bother you ?.

Comment: Do you have Butter Knife set up correctly? I'm assuming that's what you're trying to use here (that's where the `@BindView` annotation comes from, anyway). Are other Butter Knife annotations being recognized for you?

Comment: @pushasha i uploaded the dependencies can you take a look

Comment: Hmmm, I just created a new project and added the same dependencies, and I'm not getting that error. Not sure what to tell you :(
... Just to double-check, you have `import butterknife.BindViews;` at the top of the file in which you're trying to use this annotation, right?

Comment: @pushasha yep , and i  have something to tell  it was  before only '@bind' and i got some errors  then  i modified the butterknife to 8.4.0 and replace '@bind' with Bindviews
thanks a lot for your help  !